# Indexed access with deletion

Tags: ds.data-structures, randomized-algorithms, amortized-analysis

As part of a larger data structure that I am working on, I have the following sub-problem:

I start with $n$ slots in an array.  Initially all slots are valid.  I want to support two operations:

- `delete(i)`: delete the $i$-th slot in the array (by replacing its content with an `invalid` mark.)
- `lookup(o)`: return the index of the slot that holds the $o$-th still valid entry.

As an example, let's start with `ar := ['a','b','c','d','e']` and show the results of a few operations:

- `lookup(2)`: returns `2`
- `delete(2)`: now `ar == ['a','b',null,'d','e']`
- `lookup(2)`: returns `3`
- `delete(0)`: now `ar == [null,'b',null,'d','e']`
- `lookup(2)`: returns `4`

The solution doesn't actually have to keep the array around.  All I care about here is that lookup gives the right index.

I know that I can solve the problem with $O(log n)$ worst-case runtime per operation.  I am interested in whether it is possible to find a solution with $O(1)$ amortised, expected runtime per operation.  ('Expected' as in expected value averaged over random choices your algorithm might make, but for worst case input.)

Of course, randomisation and amortisation aren't a must.  I'd be even happier with a deterministic and worst-case bound.

Please either give a solution or an argument why a solution is not possible.

(I suspect a solution is possible, more or less because we can do bucket sort in linear time.  So a reduction of the problem to the $O(n log n)$ bound for comparison based sorting isn't possible.  We are explicitly dealing with small natural numbers only here.)

In addition, I'm interested in any solution that's faster than $O(log n)$ per operation.  Constant time is just what I am aiming for.  I would also be interested in a solution in important special cases, eg like all deletions coming before all lookups, or the sequence of operations being known up-front instead of an online solution.

Another detail: all runtimes are for something like the word RAM model.  Or more practically: I am interested in something that I can implement to run fast on real computers.

I am also interested in any pointers you have to relevant literature.

Comment: Do you think the following can be done in $O(n)$ time?  *Given two permutations $\pi$ and $q$ of $[n]$, compute the vector $x$ such that, for each $t\in [n]$, $x_t$ is the number of pairs $(s, \pi_s)$ such that $s \in [t]$ and $\pi_s \le q_t$.*  It seems to me that if your desired data structure exists, then this could be done [think of this as, at each time $t\in [n]$, bit $\pi_s$ is toggled from 0 to 1, and then $x_t$ is the number of bits set to 1 that have index at most $q_t$], but my intuition is that this cannot be done in $O(n)$ time.

Comment: If all deletions come before lookups (one of the special cases you mention), then isn't it easy to do it in $O(n)$ time?  (When the first lookup occurs, just scan the array, filtering out the deleted items, and putting the non-deleted items in order into a new array.)

Comment: @NealYoung Yes, that's what I had in mind. And I wonder how far you can push that idea.

Answer (score 3):

This is a subproblem of dynamic rank select, and can be done in $O(\log n / \log w)$, following ["Dynamic Integer Sets with Optimal Rank, Select, and Predecessor Search"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.3045.pdf).

Comment: Note: the parameter $w$ in this answer is the word size, so in the standard model $w=\Theta(\log n)$, giving time $O(\log(n)/\log\log n)$.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the paper. That's a good upper bound for what I am looking for. I hope that since I am interested in a sub problem and in amortised runtime, we can do better.